# Error in using Picasso to fetch image in Recyclerview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, picasso

I want to use Picasso to fetch image from the json url but don't know how to use in RecyclerView.
**Picasso.with(context).load(String.valueOf(users.get(position))).into(holder.avatar);**

i am getting error in with method how i can define the context???

**UserAdapter.java**

```
public class UserAdapter extends 
          RecyclerView.Adapter<UserAdapter.UserViewHolder> {

    ArrayList<User> users = new ArrayList<>();

    public UserAdapter(ArrayList<User> users) {
        this.users = users;
    }

    @Override
    public UserViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.items,parent,false);

        return new UserViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(UserViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.login.setText(users.get(position).getUser_login());
        holder.type.setText(users.get(position).getType());
        Picasso.with(context).load(String.valueOf(users.get(position))).into(holder.avatar);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return users.size();
    }



    public class UserViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        TextView login;
        TextView type;
        ImageView avatar;

        public UserViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            login = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.login);
            type = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.type);
            avatar = (ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.avatar);
        }
    }
  }
```

Comment: you have two option either get context from acctivity or fragment and pass to  adapter or use layout context

Comment: 1. First, you need to pass context from the activity.
2. CHange from Picasso.with(context).load(String.valueOf(users.get(position))).into(holder.avatar);

To:
  Picasso.with(context).load(users.get(position).getAvatarUrl()).into(holder.avatar);

Comment: your question should sound like `how to get context into RecyclerView Adapter`, not what you asked.

Comment: @VladMatvienko yes how can i definie context in picasso??

Comment: just use search, you will find answer in ~20 seconds.

Comment: @ShubhamKumar just add Context context to your constructor of adapter. and where you are calling this pass the context of activity or fragment.

Comment: @VishvaDave thanks for it..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use this

```
private Context context;
private ArrayList<User> users = new ArrayList<>();
private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
//constructor

public UserAdapter(ArrayList<User> users, Context context) {
    this.users = users;
    this.context = context;
    this.layoutInflater=layoutInfalter.from(context);
}

   @Override
public UserViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    View view = layoutInfalter.inflate(R.layout.items,parent,false);

    return new UserViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(UserViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.login.setText(users.get(position).getUser_login());
    holder.type.setText(users.get(position).getType());
    Picasso.with(context).
    load(String.valueOf(users.get(position)))
    .into(holder.avatar);

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return users.size();
}



public class UserViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    TextView login;
    TextView type;
    ImageView avatar;

    public UserViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        login = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.login);
        type = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.type);
        avatar = (ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.avatar);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try to get context from `activity` or `fragment`

```
Context context; 
  public UserAdapter(ArrayList<User> users, Context context) {
        this.users = users;
        this.context = context;
   }
```

call you adapter like this,

```
UserAdapter adapter = new UserAdapter(usermodel, context);
```

here context will `activity context` or `fragment context` or `getApllicationContext()`

Now u will able to call Picasso to fetch image from server `Picasso.with(context).load(String.valueOf(users.get(position))).into(holder.avatar);`

Comment: Also need change 
from Picasso.with(context).load(String.valueOf(users.get(position))).into(holder.avatar); 
To: Picasso.with(context).load(users.get(position).getAvatarUrl()).into(holder.avatar);

Comment: as i do not abut what data type he is using so i just add code which he is using. if he is using string than he do not need to String.ValueOf()

Comment: I just say his model is User Type. That I was saying to change that. Please check it

 ArrayList<User> users = new ArrayList<>();

And

 holder.login.setText(users.get(position).getUser_login());
        holder.type.setText(users.get(position).getType());
        Picasso.with(context).load(String.valueOf(users.get(position))).into(holder.avatar);